# Issues after installation of oneAPI intel ToolKit on Debian 10

Tags: python, linux, intel, intel-oneapi

I have just install oneAPI Base Toolkit and HPC toolkit. As it is indicated into doc, I have put into my `~/.zshrc` :

```
source /opt/intel/oneapi/setvars.sh
```

Now 2 problems occur :

First, when I open a new terminal, I have systematically the long message appearing before having the hand on the terminal : how to make this long message be silencious ?

```
:: initializing oneAPI environment ...
   zsh: ZSH_VERSION = 5.7.1
:: advisor -- latest
:: ccl -- latest
:: clck -- latest
:: compiler -- latest
:: dal -- latest
:: debugger -- latest
:: dev-utilities -- latest
:: dnnl -- latest
:: dpcpp-ct -- latest
:: dpl -- latest
:: inspector -- latest
:: intelpython -- latest
/opt/intel/oneapi/intelpython/latest/etc/conda/activate.d/xgboost_activate.sh:16: = not found
:: ipp -- latest
:: ippcp -- latest
:: ipp -- latest
:: itac -- latest
:: mkl -- latest
:: mpi -- latest
:: tbb -- latest
:: vpl -- latest
:: vtune -- latest
:: oneAPI environment initialized ::
```

Secondly, As you can see, I have in this message of initialization an error :

```
/opt/intel/oneapi/intelpython/latest/etc/conda/activate.d/xgboost_activate.sh:16: = not found
```

I edited this file :

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Copyright 2003-2021 Intel Corporation.
#
# This software and the related documents are Intel copyrighted materials, and
# your use of them is governed by the express license under which they were
# provided to you (License). Unless the License provides otherwise, you may
# not use, modify, copy, publish, distribute, disclose or transmit this
# software or the related documents without Intel's prior written permission.
#
# This software and the related documents are provided as is, with no express
# or implied warranties, other than those that are expressly stated in the
# License.
#

if [ "${OCL_ICD_FILENAMES}" == "" ]
then
    export OCL_ICD_FILENAMES_RESET=1
    export OCL_ICD_FILENAMES=libintelocl.so
fi
```

Could this be a conflict with `conda` or another thing?

Why do I get these problems on Linux? On MacOS 11.3, there is no issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Oneapi /opt/intel/oneapi/setvars.sh script for debian OS expects the **default shell to be bash**. The error is because you are using zsh and syntax difference in bash vs zsh.

The **xgboost_activate.sh** has the standard [] which is not supported by zsh. In zsh Double [[]] are to be used instead.

Double [[]] are an extension to the standard [] and are supported by bash and other shells (e.g. zsh, ksh).

You can replace '[' and ']' with '[[' and ']]' respectively in "**/opt/intel/oneapi/intelpython/latest/etc/conda/activate.d/xgboost_activate.sh**:16"

i.e replacing the below line

```
if [ "${OCL_ICD_FILENAMES}" == "" ]
```

with

```
if [[ "${OCL_ICD_FILENAMES}" == "" ]]
```